# Prevent TypeScript from expanding a string literal type into a string type when passing it through a function

Tags: typescript

How do we prevent TypeScript from expanding a string literal type into a string?

E.g. [in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20PropertyName%20%3D%20'Property1'%20%7C%20'Property2'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ObjectWithPropertyName%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Property1%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Property2%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Aconst%20obj1%3A%20ObjectWithPropertyName%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B'Property1'%5D%3A%20'works'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20prop%3A%20PropertyName%20%3D%20'Property1'%3B%0D%0Aconst%20obj2%3A%20ObjectWithPropertyName%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bprop%5D%3A%20'works'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20func%20%3D%20(prop%3A%20PropertyName)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20obj%3A%20ObjectWithPropertyName%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bprop%5D%3A%20%22fails%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20funcToo%20%3D%20(prop%3A%20PropertyName)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20propInner%3A%20PropertyName%20%3D%20prop%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20obj%3A%20ObjectWithPropertyName%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BpropInner%5D%3A%20%22fails%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

```
type PropertyName = 'Property1' | 'Property2';

type ObjectWithPropertyName =
    { Property1: string; } |
    { Property2: string; };

const obj1: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
    ['Property1']: 'works',
}

const prop: PropertyName = 'Property1';
const obj2: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
    [prop]: 'works',
}

const func = (prop: PropertyName) => {
    const obj: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
        [prop]: "fails",
    };
};

const funcToo = (prop: PropertyName) => {
    const propInner: PropertyName = prop;
    const obj: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
        [propInner]: "fails",
    };
};
```

In the last case the error is this:

> Property 'Property1' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: string; }' but required in type 'ObjectWithPropertyName'.

Comment: but `ObjectWithPropertyName` can have only `Property1` not `Property2` as `prop` could be.. Even if you fix this, the type will still be inferred to `{ [x: string]: string; }`. I don't think you will get away without a type assertion here..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Nice catch. I updated the question to address that concern.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I haven't even been able to make it work with a type assertion.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works for the `const` example is that there typescript knows `prop` can only be `'Property1'`. When you deal with parameters that can have any of a number of value, so typescript will infer a type with an index signature.

For example, while not particularly useful, this also works, since prop can only be `Property1`:

```
const func = (prop: 'Property1') => {
    const obj: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
        [prop]: "fails",
    } ;
};
```

The simplest solution is to use a type assertion to force the type you want for `obj`:

```
const func = (prop: PropertyName) => {
    const obj = {
        [prop]: "fails",
    } as ObjectWithPropertyName;
};
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might consider a different approach, for example we can capture the actual constant passed in an return a `Record` that contains whatever that key is:

```
const func = <T extends PropertyName>(prop: T) => {
    const obj : Record<T, string> = {
        [prop]: "ok",
    };
    return obj;
};
func('Property1').Property1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not passing through a function that causes this.

When it 'works', it works because somehow the compiler is still narrowing the type of `prop` to `Property1`

```
const prop: PropertyName = 'Property1';
const obj2: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
    [prop]: 'works',
}
```

because if you add type assertion `'Property1' as PropertyName` it starts failing with the same error

```
const prop: PropertyName = 'Property1' as PropertyName;
const obj2: ObjectWithPropertyName = {
    [prop]: 'works',
}
```

Essentially, when `prop` has union type `'Property1' | 'Property2'`, the value `{[prop]: 'something'}` is not assignable to `{Property1: string}`, and it's not assignable to `{Property2: string}` either, making it nonassignable to the union type.

You can make it work by doing exhaustive check like this:

```
const func = (prop: PropertyName) => {
    const obj: ObjectWithPropertyName = 
        prop === 'Property1' ? { [prop]: "works" } : { [prop]: "works" }
};
```

Comment: Yeah the exhaustive check version is the typesafe solution but it gets really painful really fast :(

Comment: Yes, someone really ought to teach the compiler how to do case analysis